# US Political Contributions Disclosure Form

Tags: united-states, irs, contribution, employment, tax-forms

I've been told I have to fill out a form for political contributions by my employer (a financial services firm). I googled it, and came up with [Form 8872](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/political-organizations/political-organization-filing-and-disclosure), but that looks like a form for organizations, not individuals.

Does anyone know the right form for an individual to fill out in order to report contributions to PACs?

Comment: If your employer told you to fill out a particular form, I'd ask the employer to point you to the particular form.  I can't see any reason that the IRS would care about an individual's non-deductible political contributions.  I can see reasons that various regulatory agencies would care about contributions made by employees of regulated firms so I would guess that it's a form from one of those regulators.  Or an internal company form they use to aggregate information for one of those regulators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The political entity that is accepting the donation, has to [document the donation](https://www.fec.gov/help-candidates-and-committees/filing-reports/individual-contributions/). This includes the following information:

> To itemize a contribution, the committee discloses:
>
> - Name of the source of receipt
> - Mailing address
> - Employer (if from an individual)
> - Occupation (if from an individual)
> - Election to which a contribution or loan was designated (indicated by checking “primary,” “general,” or “other” in the election
>   designation box)
> - Date of receipt
> - Amount of receipt
> - Aggregate election-cycle-to-date total of all receipts from the source

I believe the employer information allows the FEC to know if a company is using individuals to get around the limits on corporate donations. If the election isn't federal ( school board/], county/city council, state house) then the rules and the forms will be different.

I know that US government employees have limitations on their political activities, but they can still contribute. I have never had an employer ask me to contribute, nor have they asked me to tell them if I contributed.

Though if my person was something that was linked company such as founder or CEO then citizens and politicians could think that I am the company.  Or if my job was as a lobbyist, then who I contribute to could reflect on the company.

In any case the company will have to provide the form they require. Because these contributions are not tax deductible, there isn't even an IRS that can be used.